# Android Location's Time

Tags: android, math, gps

I'm creating an Android app, and see something weird. I'm using locations, and GPS, and I'd like to log each location's "oldness" (the how-long-is-that-location thing). But I can't afford to exclude the old devices, so I cannot use the Location.getElapsedRealtimeNanos() function. But I tried that also. So, here's my code:

```
// mLocationClient is a Play Services' LocationClient, I've connected, and did
// everything else, the doc says.
Location loc = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
Log.v(TAG, "Current Unix epoch:   " + new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis());
Log.v(TAG, "Location's Unix time: " + loc.getTime());
Log.v(TAG, "RealTimeNanos:        " + loc.getElapsedRealtimeNanos());
```

It gives something like this:

```
Current Unix epoch:   1409308776449
Location's Unix time: 1409308735346
RealTimeNanos:        13620832279607
```

I thought, that the `currenttimemillis` - `location'stimemillis` should be `realtimenanos` / 1.000.000.

The `currenttimemillis` - `location'stimemillis` seems right to me, it says, that the location is almost a minute old. It's possible, I've got WiFi here, my GPS is turned on, and I'm playing with this app for a while, so the location is always in use.

But the `realtimenanos`? If I'm right, I get the time in seconds by divide that by 1.000.000.000. That is 13620 seconds. That would mean, that is the location given by the mLocationClient is more than 3 hours old! It's not possible, 'cause the given coordinates points to my actual position, and I wasn't here until 1,5 hours before.

Can you help me, to understand this?